# Entity Framework with MVVM problem. Violation of PRIMARY KEY constraint The duplicate key value is (2, 2)

Tags: entity-framework, mvvm

I've been messing with this for 5 hours and I gave up.

I did basically identical relationship before and worked and now when I'm saving in my MVVM project, I get this error:

> SqlException: Violation of PRIMARY KEY constraint 'PK_dbo.LecturerMeeting'. Cannot insert duplicate key in object 'dbo.LecturerMeeting'. The duplicate key value is (2, 2).

And also:

> An error occurred while saving entities that do not expose foreign key properties for their relationships. The EntityEntries property will return null because a single entity cannot be identified as the source of the exception. Handling of exceptions while saving can be made easier by exposing foreign key properties in your entity types. See the InnerException for details.

I have 2 model classes, `Meeting` and `Lecturer`. In `Lecturer` class, I define in constructor:

```
public Lecturer()
{
    Meetings = new Collection<Meeting>();
}
```

And also

```
public ICollection<Meeting> Meetings { get; set; }
```

Same in the `Meeting` class

```
public Meeting()
{
    Students = new Collection<Student>();
    Lecturers= new Collection<Lecturer>();
}
```

And:

```
public ICollection<Lecturer> Lecturers { get; set; }
```

But when I created a many-to-many relationship between meetings and student, EF created a table `MeetingStudent`.

Now it created `LecturerMeeting`, don't know if this changes anything

SQL code for `LecturerMeeting` relationship:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[LecturerMeeting] 
(
    [Lecturer_Id] INT NOT NULL,
    [Meeting_Id]  INT NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT [PK_dbo.LecturerMeeting] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([Lecturer_Id] ASC, [Meeting_Id] ASC),
    CONSTRAINT [FK_dbo.LecturerMeeting_dbo.Lecturer_Lecturer_Id] FOREIGN KEY ([Lecturer_Id]) REFERENCES [dbo].[Lecturer] ([Id]) ON DELETE CASCADE,
    CONSTRAINT [FK_dbo.LecturerMeeting_dbo.Meeting_Meeting_Id] FOREIGN KEY ([Meeting_Id]) REFERENCES [dbo].[Meeting] ([Id]) ON DELETE CASCADE
);
GO

CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [IX_Lecturer_Id]
    ON [dbo].[LecturerMeeting]([Lecturer_Id] ASC);
GO

CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [IX_Meeting_Id]
    ON [dbo].[LecturerMeeting]([Meeting_Id] ASC);
```

Please help.

Comment: I also mention that this occurs while saving inside MeetingDetailViewModel. I have DataGrid where i put Lecturer and save him. Or at least im trying because its not working. So I want to assign lecturer to my meeting. I want to havy many to many relationship because Lecturer can be part of many meetings.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to find answer. Finally.
I didnt incluced another property when i get my Meeting from context.
I had

```
public async override Task<Meeting> GetByIdAsync(int id)
        {
            return await Context.Meetings.Include(m => m.Students).SingleAsync(m => m.Id == id);
```

Insted of:

```
public async override Task<Meeting> GetByIdAsync(int id)
        {
            return await Context.Meetings.Include(m => m.Students).Include(m => m.Lecturers)
                .SingleAsync(m => m.Id == id); 
        }
```

Too stupid to find that faster.

Comment: how did this omission result in the duplicate PK?